# Are nested static classes similar to non-static classes for REST request-body?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-restcontroller

I am using a Spring Boot to design REST API. I want to know what difference it will make while using nested classes in request body?

REST Endpoint:

```
@PostMapping("/create")
public void (@RequestBody RequestData.UserDetails details) {}
```

My RequestData class:

```
public class RequestData {
  public static final class UserDetails {
     private String name;
  }
}
```

So my question is which of the following class definations is safe?

1. Creating a seperate class for UserDetails to get requested data
2. Creating a nested class as stated above

Do nested classes affect during multiple concurrent requests or in some other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do nested classes affect during multiple concurrent requests or in some other way?

No, the request body will be mapped to an instance of the `RequestData.UserDetails` or simply `UserDetails` if it is a separate class. If you don't store this is instance as a class attribute in your Controllers, Services, etc, there is no concurrent requests concern because each request to your Controller will have its own instance of such a class and multi-threading is not a problem because you are not storing state.

This means that having a nested class or a separate class is irrelevant to the fact that you have a threadsafe Controller, Service, etc or not. The important thing is to not store state on them.

In this case, having a nested class or a separate class is more a question of taste and organization than anything else.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @joão-dias. You said that not to store state on them. My nested classes have all the fields marked as final, the class is also static final itself and there are only getter methods and no setter methods. Does this make my class stateless?    You also said that having a nested class or a separate class is more a question of taste and organization? I would like to know what would you prefer? Separate class or Nested class?

Comment: The stateless thing is relevant for the Controllers and Services (that should not store any state in them). For your POJOs, one important feature is to be immutable because by being mutable they are error-prone (take a look at https://www.baeldung.com/java-immutable-object). I would have them in a separate class, but then again, that is just me. I would also be ok with code with nested class.